# What do you call two surjective functions that have the same codomain?

Tags: functions, definition

Let $f$ be a surjective function from $D_f$ to $C$, and let $g$ be a surjective function from $D_g$ to $C$ such that $C = \{ f(d) | d \in D_f \} = \{ g(d) | d \in D_g \}$. Assume $f \neq g$. Is there a standard term to describe this relationship? Are they symmetric perhaps?

Comment: "Now, if $D_f = D_g$ then we would say that $f = g$" - that's obviously not true.

Comment: You appear to be claiming that all surjective functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ are equal, but this is clearly not the case.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. It could be the case that despite having the same Domain and Codomain that $f(d) \neq g(d)$ for all $d$ in their common domain. I'll edit that. My question remains though - is there a term to describe the relationship between $f$ and $g$ - especially when they are not equal?

Comment: No, there is no such term in general use.

Comment: @lulu got it, thanks :) For more context - I want to describe the relationship between two distinct cycles of a sequence S, where both cycles have the same period but where $C_1 \neq C_2$.